# Resolving keys in groovy maps

Tags: groovy

I am wondering why the value of the key resolves to null when it is constructed from a string and a variable `def theKey="command$i"`

```
def workingDir1 = "my/path"
def command1 = "command1"

def i=1
def theKey="command$i"

Map<String,List> map1  = new HashMap<String,String>();
map1.put("command1", workingDir1); 


def value = map1.get(theKey)
println "$theKey $value"

value = map1.get(command1)
println "$command1 $value"
```

Output:

```
command1 null
command1 my/path
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is different classes. `def theKey="command$i"` creates a `GString` and `map1.put("command1", workingDir1);` uses a `String` for the key.

To get your value out using `theKey` you have to do:

```
map1.get(theKey.toString())
```

Comment: Maybe not a bug, but I think it's a defect that the language architects should look into - to turn GStrings into Strings when used as map keys. Thoughts?

Comment: It's specifically mentioned in the documentation

Comment: Thanks doelleri that did the trick!  I didn't realize they were of different String types.

Comment: @IvoryMicky Any time you use `${}` in a double quoted string you will get a `GString` instead of a `String`.